# How to create a multiple typed object pool in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, object, pool

Im trying to create a system capable of allocating any type, and grouping same types together in arrays.

I want to be able to retrieve each array later using so I can iterate over each type.

Something like this:

```
ObjectDatabase
{
   template<typename T>
   T* Allocate();

   template<typename T>
   Array<T>& GetObjects();
}
```

My Array type is actually a pool so allocation/deletion is fast.

I thought about mapping each Array in a std::map using an int representing the type id for each T, but then each type T would need to inherit from a base class, so it can be stored in the map, and thus leading to casting when I iterate over the array.

I think this pattern has been done before but I'm not sure how.

Can someone help?

**Update:**

So I'm trying to basically create a structure like this:

```
struct ObjectDatabase
{
    Array<Entities> mEntities;
    Array<Transforms> mTransforms; 
    Array<Physics> mPhysics; 
    Array<Graphics> mGraphics; 
}
```

But I wanted to somehow create the set of arrays at compile time.. using templates?

Then provide template functions to get access to each array, and to allocate from each array

Comment: Aren't you reinventing the variant? You can either use boost::variant or QVariant as T and avoid template, or at a look at how they are implemented if you want your own object

Comment: You can wrap the array (e.g. `vector<T>`) as a data member into a class template that derives from a base class. E.g. `struct base { /* pure virtual functions */ }; template<class T> struct wrapper : base { vector<T> arr; /*virtual functions*/ };` And then store a `map<int, wrapper>` via some type->`int` mapping.

Comment: I don't want any virtual functions, as T is just a structure in all cases with no methods. Im just storing sets of data. You can think of it as a set of arrays, where each array stores a single type.

If I use boost::variant I believe I have to fetch the appropriate type for element in the array as I iterate which will slow things down..

Comment: What I was suggesting is to *wrap the array* in a class with virtual functions. Inside this class you can access the array w/o any overhead. Something like this: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/45546ec43180306e

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use templates to do type elision.  Here's an example that may be similar to what you're looking for.  The `ObjectDatabase` class uses templates and polymorphism internally to do type elision so the classes used don't have any constraints on them (other than the normal constraints for being placed in a standard library container).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <deque>
#include <map>
#include <cassert>
using namespace std;

struct ObjectDatabase {
    ObjectDatabase() { }

    template<typename T>
    T &allocate() {
        deque<T> &a = getObjects<T>();
        a.push_back(T());
        return a.back();
    }

    template<typename T>
    deque<T> &getObjects() {
        CollectionBase *&el = m_obdb[typeid(T).name()];
        if ( not el )
            el = new Collection<T>();
        Collection<T> *elc = dynamic_cast<Collection<T>*>(el);
        assert(elc);
        deque<T> &a = elc->elements;
        return a;
    }

    ~ObjectDatabase() {
        for ( ObDB::iterator i=m_obdb.begin(); i!=m_obdb.end(); ++i)
            delete i->second;
    }
private:
    ObjectDatabase(ObjectDatabase const &);
    ObjectDatabase &operator=(ObjectDatabase const &);

    struct CollectionBase {
        virtual ~CollectionBase() { }
    };
    template<typename T>
    struct Collection : CollectionBase {
        deque<T> elements;
    };
    typedef map<string, CollectionBase *> ObDB;
    ObDB m_obdb;
};

struct Foo {
    Foo() : name("Generic Foo") { }
    char const *name;
};

struct Bar {
    string name;
};

int main() {
    ObjectDatabase obdb;
    obdb.allocate<Foo>().name = "My First Foo";
    obdb.allocate<Bar>().name = "My First Bar";
    {
        Foo &f = obdb.allocate<Foo>();
        f.name = "My Second Foo";
        Bar &b = obdb.allocate<Bar>();
        b.name = "My Second Bar";
    }
    obdb.allocate<Foo>();
    obdb.allocate<Bar>();
    {
        cout << "Printing Foo Names\n";
        deque<Foo> &foos = obdb.getObjects<Foo>();
        for ( deque<Foo>::iterator i = foos.begin(); i!=foos.end(); ++i )
            cout << "   -> " << i->name << "\n";
    }
    {
        cout << "Printing Bar Names\n";
        deque<Bar> &bars = obdb.getObjects<Bar>();
        for ( deque<Bar>::iterator i = bars.begin(); i!=bars.end(); ++i )
            cout << "   -> " << i->name << "\n";
    }
}
```

When I run this program, I get this output:

```
Printing Foo Names
   -> My First Foo
   -> My Second Foo
   -> Generic Foo
Printing Bar Names
   -> My First Bar
   -> My Second Bar
   ->
```

This shows that the individual objects are stored in containers specific to their own type.  You'll notice that `Foo` and `Bar` are nothing special, just regular aggregates.  (`Foo` would even be a POD if it weren't for its default constructor.)

**======== EDIT ========**

If you don't want to use RTTI, you need to get rid of the `typeid` and `dynamic_cast`.

Getting rid of the `dynamic_cast` is fairly simple --- you don't actually need it.  You can use `static_cast` instead; you just can't check that the derived type is correct with the `assert()` anymore.  (But if the type was wrong, it would be a bug anyway.)

The `typeid` is a bit trickier, since that is used to construct an identifier to differentiate between different concrete types.  But you can use some template magic and static objects to replace the `string` (from `type_info::name()`) with a simple `void const *` pointer:

```
template<typename T>
struct TypeTag {
    static char const tag;
};
template<typename T>
char const TypeTag<T>::tag = '\0';

template<typename T>
void const *get_typemarker() {
    return &TypeTag<T>::tag;
}
```

Now we can use `get_typemarker<T>()` to return a `void const *` key into the map.  We change the type of `ObDB`'s key from `string` to `void const *` and replace `typeid(T).name()` with `get_typemarker<T>()`.  I've tested it and it gives the same output in my test program as the RTTI-enabled version.

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I'm after! Thank you I can work with this. Although I don't have RTTI enabled.. How would it work without typeid() and dynamic_cast?

Comment: @Mash, I've added some new material to the bottom of the answer that should help you with what you want.

Comment: @Mash I'm pretty sure `typeid(T)` is *not* RTTI. It's not a run-time feature that checks the type of some object, but provides a type information object *of a type*. The `dynamic_cast` is simply not necessary, assuming unique type names.

Comment: "The dynamic_cast<> operation and typeid operator in C++ are part of RTTI."

And also I wasn't aware of this!

"When applied to an expression of polymorphic type, evaluation of a typeid expression may involve runtime overhead (a virtual table lookup), otherwise typeid expression is resolved at compile time."

I normally work in a games industry where RTTI is disabled, so always like alternative solutions that don't rely on those features.

Thanks so much for this answer! Im not sure I entirely understand the point of collection base and collection<T> yet.

Comment: @Mash, the reason for `CollectionBase` and `Collection<T>` is so the `ObjectDatabase` can use a `map` to handle different containers for different types.  `CollectionBase` serves as a common base class for all the various containers so they can be stored in a single `map` (as pointers).  A `Collection<T>` holds a specific container for a set of objects, and it inherits from `CollectionBase` so that it can be held along with other `Collection<T>`s of other types.  To access each specific container, you must downcast.  (`CollectionBase` also provides the needed virtual destructor for clean-up.)

Comment: Ah I think I get it.. If I were to try and store Collection<T> in the map, then the whole class would need to be templated to recognise T, obvisouly that doesn't make sense. But having CollectionBase allows T to be applied only to the calling function. Nice trick! I also wasn't aware of the not keyword.

Comment: @AdamH.Peterson I do have one more question, Sorry I'm squeezing all your tricks out from you! 

Theres a certain runtime overheard allocating the collections. My collections are object pools so they may be fairly large. Is there some way to perform that allocation at compile time?

Comment: Also that type tag thing is cool, almost like its adding a static member to each concrete type at compile time..

Comment: @Mash, I can think of a few ways to override the allocation of the collections, but they're kind of awkward to stick in a StackOverflow comment like this, and they have various trade-offs.  The basic idea would be to take over the `el = new Collection<T>();` line and have it do something different.  You could call a templated function whose default implementation simply does what the current code does now, but you could specialize it for the types you know you'll use.  (You'll also have to instrument the `delete i->second;` line in the destructor to not delete the statically allocated ones.)

Comment: @Mash, the statically allocated tweak I mention above gets touchy if `ObjectDatabase` isn't a singleton (since only one `ObjectDatabase` can use the statically allocated container, or they end up sharing it).  However, if `ObjectDatabase` _is_ a singleton, you could call a templated free function that has a local static variable that is the collection.  That would cause the containers to be allocated in global memory rather than the freestore.  Perhaps: `template<typename T> Collection<T> *getCollection() { static Collection<T> c; return &c; }`.  (Again, you'll need to fix the destructor.)